# Angular 9 Stop using deprecated functions from utils

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, import, angular9

In our app we used to make use of util functions found in node's core (`@types/node/util.d.ts`). These functions have been [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_deprecated_apis), and I want to know how can we make use of another library, like [core-util-is](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-util-is), or even port those to a custom library/file with exported functions within our project - in order to get rid of the esLint errors.

> Note: I dont want to disable the deprecated rule in eslint.

The easy part is to port those functions straight into our project, but when using them (for instance `isNullOrUndefined(myObject)`, vsCode will try to import that function from the deprecated function:

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'utils';
```

How can I force vsCode (Or typescript, I don't have enough knowledge on this subject to know which is responsible for importing) to skip importing from the deprecated `utils` and to import from the correct external library/custom file in our project?

```
import { isNullOrUndefined } from './customUtils';
```